# two columns with same width, but first has static position, 2nd absolute

Tags: css, position

I want to make a responsive site with a 2-column layout.
For desktop screens the two columns should appear and for small screens (smartphones) only one of the column should be displayed.

To switch between the columns, the user have to make a horizontal swipe (right-to-left or left-to-right). This works fine (for desktop user: use the mouse and do a drag&drop).

The problem is: the right column has a **absolute** position. The left column has a **static** position (I think) and a **width of 100%**. For small screens the complete layout is relative, by the media query. **I don't know which width value the right column** should have. I try multiple percentage values (100%-90%), but when I though I found the right value, I realized it only works for a specific window width. When I resize the window for some pixels, it breaks.

**So both columns should be within / same width as the red border (in the fiddle).**

**Don't forget to resize the result window, to simulate a small screen!**
**You can also switch back to the left column, make an inverse swipe / drag&drop.**

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sUPfh/1/

I have another solution (2) where the width is okay, but then the slide effect doesn't work properly.
The right column is below the left column during the slide effect. When the effect finish, the right column suddenly appears at the right place, but it should slide from the side.

You can try both solutions, just delete / comment one of the solutions for the right column in the css window:

```
/* solution 1 (width is not really percentage, when resize the window, but slide effect ok) */
position: absolute;
width: 94%; /* width only ok if the window width is about 695px */

/* solution 2 (width ok, but wrong slide effect */
/*
position: static;
width: 100%;
*/
```

PS: I use Twitter Bootstrap with less and a custom grid layout, so I add the full generated css. The important css rules should be at the end in the css window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the horizontal body padding, which was set to 20px. Or alternative to set a percentage value for it.